# generating correlated numbers in numpy / pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, correlation

I’m trying to generate simulated student grades in 4 subjects, where a student record is a single row of data.  The code shown here will generate normally distributed random numbers with a mean of 60 and a standard deviation of 15.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(15 * np.random.randn(5, 4) + 60, columns=['Math', 'Science', 'History', 'Art'])
```

What I can’t figure out is how to make it so that a student’s Science mark is highly correlated to their Math mark, and that their History and Art marks are less so, but still somewhat correlated to the Math mark.

I’m neither a statistician or an expert programmer, so a less sophisticated but more easily understood solution is what I’m hoping for.

Comment: Do you have any grade data that demonstrates those correlations?  It would make generating a valid covariance matrix easier.  You don't need to post it here (privacy), just what format that data would have.

Comment: In any case, what you would want is to generate the average vector and the covariance matrix, and use `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.rvs()` to generate random data with that distribution.

Answer (score 6):

Let's put what has been suggested by @Daniel into code.

**Step 1**

Let's import `multivariate_normal`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn
```

**Step 2**

Let's construct covariance data and generate data:

```
cov = np.array([[1, 0.8,.7, .6],[.8,1.,.5,.5],[0.7,.5,1.,.5],[0.6,.5,.5,1]])
cov

array([[ 1. ,  0.8,  0.7,  0.6],
       [ 0.8,  1. ,  0.5,  0.5],
       [ 0.7,  0.5,  1. ,  0.5],
       [ 0.6,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ]])
```

This is the key step. Note, that covariance matrix has `1's` in diagonal, and the covariances decrease as you step from left to right.

Now we are ready to generate data, let's sat 1'000 points:

```
scores = mvn.rvs(mean = [60.,60.,60.,60.], cov=cov, size = 1000)
```

Sanity check (from covariance matrix to simple correlations):

```
np.corrcoef(scores.T):

array([[ 1.        ,  0.78886583,  0.70198586,  0.56810058],
       [ 0.78886583,  1.        ,  0.49187904,  0.45994833],
       [ 0.70198586,  0.49187904,  1.        ,  0.4755558 ],
       [ 0.56810058,  0.45994833,  0.4755558 ,  1.        ]])
```

Note, that `np.corrcoef` expects your data in rows.

Finally, let's put your data into Pandas' `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = scores, columns = ["Math", "Science","History", "Art"])
df.head()

    Math        Science     History     Art
0   60.629673   61.238697   61.805788   61.848049
1   59.728172   60.095608   61.139197   61.610891
2   61.205913   60.812307   60.822623   59.497453
3   60.581532   62.163044   59.277956   60.992206
4   61.408262   59.894078   61.154003   61.730079
```

**Step 3**

Let's visualize some data that we've just generated:

```
ax = df.plot(x = "Math",y="Art", kind="scatter", color = "r", alpha = .5, label = "Art, $corr_{Math}$ = .6")
df.plot(x = "Math",y="Science", kind="scatter", ax = ax, color = "b", alpha = .2, label = "Science, $corr_{Math}$ = .8")
ax.set_ylabel("Art and Science");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The statistical tool for that is the covariance matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance.
Each cell (i,j) is representing the dependecy between the variable i and the variable j, so in your case it can be between math and science. If there is no dependency the value would be 0.

What you did was assuming that the covariance was a diagonal matrix with the same values on the diagonal. So what you have to do is defines your covariance matrix and afterwards draw the samples from a gaussian with `numpy.random.multivariate_normal` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html or any other distribution functions.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for the responses; they were extremely useful.  I adapted the code provided by Sergey to produce the result I was looking for, which was records with Math and Science marks that are relatively close most of the time, and History and Art marks that are more independent.

The following produced data that looks reasonable:

```
cov = np.array([[1, 0.5,.2, .1],[.5,1.,.1,.1],[0.2,.1,1,.3],[0.1,.1,.3,1]])
scores = mvn.rvs(mean = [0.,0.,0.,0.], cov=cov, size = 100)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = 15 * scores + 60, columns = ["Math","Science","History", "Art"])
df.head(10)
```

The next step would be to make it so that each subject has a different mean, but I have an idea of how to do that.  Thanks again.

[example dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGlGH.jpg)