# Handling Negative Values when Calculating Average & Value

Tags: statistics

I am working on a tool for Fantasy Football that calculates the average value a player offers per million pounds of cost. It essentially boils down to their average points per game divided by their cost.

So for example, a player who costs £10m and scores an average of 5 points per game offers 0.5 points per game per million. Whereas a player who costs £8m and scores an average of 5 points per game offers 0.625 points per game per million. Clearly the player who costs £8m is better value.

My problem is, players are capable of scoring negatively, and so how do I account for that in calculating the value of a player?

To give another example, a player who costs £10m and scores an average of -2 points per game offers -0.2 points per game per million. Whereas a player who costs £8m and scores an average of -2 points per game offers -0.25 points per game per million.

Now the player who costs £10m appears to be better value because their PPG/£m is higher. This shouldn't be true, they can't be better value if they cost more but score the same points. So if I have a list of players sorted by their value, calculated in this manner, some players will incorrectly show higher than players that are technically better value.

Is there a way to account for this problem? Or is just an unfortunate fact of the system I'm using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Comment: Then what's the statistics tag for?

Comment: The statistics tag is for programming that involve statistics, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952895/generating-correlated-numbers-in-numpy-pandas

Comment: And I'm programming a tool, like I said?

Comment: You could try https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for what on-topic means. I don't think your question fits in the first four bullet points

Comment: It fits the second point.

Answer (score 0):

One simple trick will be to slightly change your formula for PPG/£m  as the ratio of the square of the average points he scored and the cost.

If you are particular about the scales, consider its positive square root.

Comment: That misrepresents the data though, as a player who scores -4 will show the same as a player who scores +4 if I'm squaring the score.

Comment: Hey @Kydos , sorry for the late response. I forgot mentioning that sign(average points) should precede the formula.